# Lucene 'join' how-to?

Tags: lucene.net, nhibernate.search

Using Nhibernate.Search at the moment.

Some code for context:

```
[Indexed]
class foo {
  [DocumentId]
  int id {get;set;}
  bar bar {get;set;}
}

[Indexed]
class bar {
  [DocumentId]
  int id {get;set;}
}
```

Question:
How to retrieve all foos where foo.bar.id==1 using IFullTextQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to include related information into the foo index you may look into the IndexedEmbeddedAttribute. This will allow you to query for relationships such as if there was a Name property on the bar object you could create a query such as this

```
IFullTextQuery query = search.CreateFullTextQuery("bar.Name:Arnis");
query.List<foo>();
```

Comment: you have to be careful when using the IndexedEmbeddedAttribute because it requires more entities to have to be loaded at indexing time.

Comment: What if i need to add this clause to query that's made with MultiFieldQueryParser?

Comment: In the constructor of the MutliFieldQueryParser it allows you to pass in a string array of fields that you want to search. Just pass in the "bar.Name" field as one of your fields.

Answer (score 0):

[Seems that `[IndexedAttribute]` is an answer.](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en/html/search-mapping.html)

Comment: Actually - i mean here IndexedEmbedded. That was typo.