# Lucene 'join' how-to? part II

Tags: lucene.net, nhibernate.search

Part I [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295139/lucene-join-how-to)...

---

**Requirement:**
search by multiple values in multiple fields **AND Where Bar.Id == argBar.Id**

```
var parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser
  (new[] { "Name", "Title" }, new SimpleAnalyzer());

parser.???(string.Format("Bar.Id:{0}",argBar.Id)); // o_0

var query = Session.CreateFullTextQuery
   (parser.Parse(searchValue), new[] { typeof(Foo) });
```

---

[Found this](http://www.devatwork.nl/articles/lucenenet/faceted-search-and-drill-down-lucenenet/):

```
Query searchQuery = MultiFieldQueryParser.Parse
  (term, new[] {"title", "description"},  
         new[] {BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD},  
         new StandardAnalyzer());
```

So, theoretically - i should be able to add `argBar.Id` and `BooleanClause.Occur.Must`, but there isn't such an overload in Lucene.Net 2.4.0.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var bq = new BooleanQuery();
bq.Add(parser.Parse(searchValue), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
bq.Add(new TermQuery
  (new Term("Bar.Id", argBar.Id.ToString()), BooleanClause.Occur.Must);

var r = Session.CreateFullTextQuery(bq, new[] {typeof(Foo)});
//victory
```